# Issue setting up CMakeLists.txt files, getting error: ld returned 1 exit status

Tags: c++, c, cmake, googletest

I'm working on a C project with CMake. I've managed to put together a folder structure for my own libs inside the project and configured the CMakeLists.txt accordingly. The project also includes a test folder with unit tests with Google's gtest.

When building the project, I get a linking error that says:

```
[ 88%] Linking CXX executable das-test
/usr/bin/ld: CMakeFiles/das-test.dir/src/misc/vector_math_tests.cpp.o: in function `VectorMathFixture_ShouldReturnUniqueElementsWithReconstructionIndexes_Test::TestBody()':
/mnt/d/Git/das/das/test/src/misc/vector_math_tests.cpp:22: undefined reference to `unique_values(int*, int, int*, int*, int*)'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make[2]: *** [test/CMakeFiles/das-test.dir/build.make:108: test/das-test] Error 1
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/Makefile2:287: test/CMakeFiles/das-test.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [Makefile:130: all] Error 2
```

I'm aware there's an undefined reference error for the function `unique_values`, however, in that source code file, I've `#include`ed the header file for it and the IDE (CLion) seems to be able to pick up the function definition as well.

Since I'm new to CMake, I believe that's what is messed up.

This is my project's structure:

[image: Project Structure]

And the CMakeLists.txt files are as follows:

- `src/filters/CMakeLists.txt`

```
set(HEADER_FILES
        ${das_SOURCE_DIR}/include/gaussian_filter.h)

set(SOURCE_FILES
        gaussian_filter.c)

add_library(dasfilters STATIC ${SOURCE_FILES} ${HEADER_FILES})

target_include_directories(dasfilters PUBLIC ${das_SOURCE_DIR}/include)
target_link_libraries(dasfilters dasmisc)
```

- `src/misc/CMakeLists.txt`

```
set(HEADER_FILES
        ${das_SOURCE_DIR}/include/gaussian.h
        ${das_SOURCE_DIR}/include/vector_math.h)

set(SOURCE_FILES
        gaussian.c
        vector_math.c)

add_library(dasmisc STATIC ${SOURCE_FILES} ${HEADER_FILES})

target_include_directories(dasmisc PUBLIC ${das_SOURCE_DIR}/include)
```

- `test/CMakeLists.txt`

```
add_subdirectory(lib)

add_executable(das-test
        src/misc/vector_math_tests.cpp
        src/main.cpp)

# manually include gtest headers
target_include_directories(das-test PRIVATE ${gtest_SOURCE_DIR}/include)

target_link_libraries(das-test dasmisc dasfilters gtest gtest_main gmock gmock_main)

add_test(NAME das-test
         COMMAND das-test --gtest_output=xml:das-tests.xml)
```

- root CMakeLists.txt

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.15)
project(das C CXX)

set(CMAKE_C_STANDARD 99)

#include_directories(include)

add_executable(das src/main.c)

target_link_libraries(das dasfilters)
target_link_libraries(das dasmisc)

target_link_libraries(das m)

add_subdirectory(src/filters)
add_subdirectory(src/misc)
add_subdirectory(test)
```

Comment: Are you compiling the file where `unique_values` is implemented?  Is it linked into your executable, possibly as one of the libraries you're building?

Comment: Since you seem to have a mixed C and C++ project here, you have to be careful that you declare the C functions in a const "C" block. Is `unique_values` a C or C++ function?  I think your compiler is looking for C, but if it's compiled as C++, it's been name mangled.

Comment: @jwdonahue `unique_values` is a C function defined in the file `src/misc/vector_math.c`. Also, no C functions are declared in C++ code files. The only part of the project that is C++ is all the code under the `test` folder, since gtest is effectively C++. So, basically, what I have is C++ code (the tests) referencing C code (what is being tested).

Comment: You forgot to show your C/C++ **code** and without this code it is impossible to help. Note, that "undefined reference" and "IDE (CLion) seems to be able to pick up the function definition as well." refers to **different aspects**: The second one means that there is a function's **declaration** (signature only) in some header. The first one means that there is no **definition** (signature with body) of the function. See also [that question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12573816/what-is-an-undefined-reference-unresolved-external-symbol-error-and-how-do-i-fix).